# Change Boolean filter in kendo UI Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

i am using build-in column filter for kendo grid and i want to change the text in boolean filter options [boolean filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFJn8.png) to `Active`-`InActive`, i already tried to use custom filter, but i prefer to use kendo filter if there is any way to change the texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution will help add it after grid is loaded.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('k-radio-label')[0].innerHTML = 'Active';
document.getElementsByClassName('k-radio-label')[1].innerHTML = 'InActive';
```

[image]

Comment: is there any way to do this with out using `JS`, or use is using custom filter template ?

Comment: @YahyaQadoome I am not much more aware of kendo grid but as i tried to search i can not see any input or parameters which can be pass to kendo grid